# Excel - Rounding Average Output Values to Lower Step Values

Tags: excel

Problem:

- I have 10 cells (A1-A10) in my workbook where I can enter values. The values are not sorted (always random).
- I have 1 cell (C4) where the average of that value is calculated with the formula: `=AVERAGEIF(A1:10,"<>0")`
- I need a formula for the cell C5 where this average is rounded to a **lower** step value (unless its already equal to one of the step values).
- My step values are:
  1,0
  1,3
  1,7
  2,0
  2,3
  2,7
  3,0
  3,3
  3,7
  4,0

Examples:

- If my average value (C4) is 3,2 I need it to show in the field C5 as 3,0.
- If my average value (C4) is 1,3 it needs to stay 1,3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C5 use this simple [LOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/lookup-function-df82ce98-edf9-46ea-8189-b0470e5e0e93) with constants.

```
=LOOKUP(C4, {1,1.3,1.7,2,2.3,2.7,3,3.3,3.7,4})
```

There was no mention of what to provide if the average was lower than 1. I'm sorry but I could not determine your system's list delimiter.

Comment: My delimiter is ; and , but I changed that myself. Thank you very much for such a simple and elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Enter your step into cells f10 to f17 (or any other cells) and
On C5 enter:
  `=IFNA(VLOOKUP(C4,$F$10:$F$17,1,0),VLOOKUP(C4,$F$10:$F$17,1,1))`